# Scheduled Batchable process in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I am trying my hands on implementing a batch process. I need some help/guidance on how to test this. All I am doing here is to display the opportunity name in the debug logs. But when I run the class scheduledBatchable which also has the test class in it in Apex test execution. The debug statements on the Opp_BatchProcess are not getting displayed. What is that I am doing wrong?

Here is the code i have

```
global class Opp_BatchProcess implements Database.Batchable < sObject >
{
    globalDatabase.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContextBC)
    {
        system.debug('Insidestart');
        returnDatabase.getQueryLocator('select name,id from opportunity');
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List <sObject> batch)
    {
        for (Sobject s : batch)
        {
            opportunity o = (opportunity)s;
            system.debug('Opp name is' + o.name);
        }
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {}
}
```

I also have a schedulable class

```
global class scheduledBatchable implements Schedulable
{
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc)
    {
        Opp_BatchProcess b = new Opp_BatchProcess();
        ID myBatchJobID = database.executebatch(b);
    }

    public static testMethod void testscheduleMerge()
    {
        Test.startTest();
        scheduledBatchable s8 = new scheduledBatchable();
        string sch = '0 0 * * 1-12 ? *';
        system.schedule('Process Trans 1', sch, s8);
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your testmethod only tests the Schedulable class. You need to test the Batchable class as well.

Try this:

```
global class scheduledBatchable implements Schedulable
{
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc)
    {
        Opp_BatchProcess b = new Opp_BatchProcess();
        ID myBatchJobID = database.executebatch(b);
    }

    public static testMethod void testscheduleMerge()
    {
        Test.startTest();
        scheduledBatchable s8 = new scheduledBatchable();
        string sch = '0 0 * * 1-12 ? *';
        system.schedule('Process Trans 1', sch, s8);
        Test.stopTest();
    }

    public static testMethod void testBatchMerge()
    {
        Test.startTest();
        Opp_BatchProcess b = new Opp_BatchProcess();
        ID myBatchJobID = database.executebatch(b);
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew, i thought that since the schedulable class is calling Opp_BatchProcess, it should cover this too..

Comment: It's common to think that it would, but executing the schedulable class doesn't actually run the batch class in testmethods.